# Why is creating a HashMap faster than creating an Object[]?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, hashmap

I've tried to build my own Map to increase the performance for a special environment, and I realized something pretty interesting: Creating a `new Hashmap<Integer,String>(2000)` is faster than `new Object[2000]` - no matter in which order I execute these commands. That's pretty confusing to me, esp. because the Hashmap constructor contains a `table = new Entry[capacity]`, according to [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html). Is there something wrong with my testbench?

```
public static void test(int amm){ //amm=1_000_000
    Map<Integer,String> m1 = null;
    Object[] arr = null;

    long time = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0; i < amm; i++){
        m1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>(2000);
    }
    System.out.println("m1: " + (System.nanoTime() - time)); //m1: 70_455_065

    time = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0; i < amm; i++){
        arr = new Object[2000];
    }
    System.out.println("arr: " + (System.nanoTime() - time)); //arr: 1_322_473_803
}
```

I'd love to see the results of testing on another computer. I've got no clue why creating a `HashMap` is 10 times faster than creating a `Object[]`.

Comment: It depends on the JDK implementation. Which JDK and version are you using to perform this test?

Comment: @BladeCoder I'm using 1.7.0_79 (IceTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) accoring to java.version.

Comment: Indeed in a close version of OpenJDK 1.7, no array is initialized in the constructor of HashMap (it's done on first insertion) which explains the speed gap: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java/?v=source

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `HashMap`, the constructor looks like:

```
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initial capacity: " +
                                           initialCapacity);
    if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
        initialCapacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
    if (loadFactor <= 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal load factor: " +
                                           loadFactor);

    this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
    threshold = initialCapacity;
    init();
}
```

And `init()` looks like:

```
/**
 * Initialization hook for subclasses. This method is called
 * in all constructors and pseudo-constructors (clone, readObject)
 * after HashMap has been initialized but before any entries have
 * been inserted.  (In the absence of this method, readObject would
 * require explicit knowledge of subclasses.)
 */
void init() {
}
```

So `initialCapacity` doesn't actually get used to create an array. Where does it get used? Look at the `put()` method.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    // hidden
}
```

When doing a put, the array is actually created. I didn't show `inflateTable()` but it does some math and initializes the array.

Comment: where's you're source Code from? I've found http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html - what says something different. I'll try it, though :)
EDIT: you're right, adding a put(5,"Hello") fixes the problem. Interesting, ty

Comment: @alexberne I used intellij's view source, which was `JDK_1.7.0_51` on MacOS

Comment: Interesting... so the OpenJDK Implementation will show different performance if you have a program which initializes a big HashMap on loading and puts elements inside when the user clicks a button. -- On OpenJDK the app will take long to load and be fast on user-interaction While on OracleJDK the app will load fast and take long on the first button-click. -- The benefit of the OracleJDK Solution is obviously being able to create a lot of unused HashMaps without much memory footprint

Comment: @Falco: I doubt that you will notice the performance impact of creating an object array of size 2000 on a button click.

Comment: @Holger probably not... But with modern Servlets which may initialize thousands of HashMaps for various attributes and classes, overall loading time and memory footprint may vary considerably

Comment: @Falco: right, but Servlets imply network transfers which outperform all of them anyway…

Comment: @Falco, nope, this code is from [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/55f6804b4352/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l486), not some Oracle proprietary patches. Oracle Java is VERY close to OpenJDK, just not all components were opened (WebStart, JMC, HotSpot for ARM etc).

Comment: @alexkasko then the Code on DocJar seems to be wrong, in their version of the OpenJDK-7 Source it looks different... strange

Answer (score 21):

An empty `HashMap` object is much smaller than an array of 2000 `Object` references. Even though you pass 2000 to the `initialCapacity` parameter of the `HashMap` constructor, it's not actually creating 2000 spaces for objects yet.